# JACK server could not be started HELP!

Tags: sound, alsa, jack, audio-recording, audio-player

I have Ubuntu 18.04.5. When opening QjackCtl i get the following ''D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry'' [1 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlhZD.png)

after that another window pops up saying ''Could not connect to JACK server as client.

- Overall operation failed.
- Unable to connect to server.
  Please check the messages window for more info.''[2 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQybH.png) and the message is- [3 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYW6K.png)
  ''23:30:47.753 Statistics reset.
  23:30:47.757 ALSA connection change.
  23:30:47.760 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
  23:30:47.796 D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry
  Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
  Cannot connect to server request channel
  jack server is not running or cannot be started
  JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
  JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
  Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
  Cannot connect to server request channel
  jack server is not running or cannot be started
  JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
  JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
  23:30:47.890 ALSA connection graph change.
  Mon Nov  9 23:30:47 2020: Starting jack server...
  Mon Nov  9 23:30:47 2020: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
  Mon Nov  9 23:30:47 2020: self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
  Mon Nov  9 23:30:47 2020: ERROR: Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
  Mon Nov  9 23:30:47 2020: Acquired audio card Audio0
  Mon Nov  9 23:30:47 2020: creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
  Mon Nov  9 23:30:47 2020: ERROR: ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
  Mon Nov  9 23:30:47 2020: Released audio card Audio0
  Mon Nov  9 23:30:47 2020: ERROR: Cannot initialize driver
  Mon Nov  9 23:30:47 2020: ERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1
  Mon Nov  9 23:30:47 2020: ERROR: Failed to open server
  Mon Nov  9 23:30:49 2020: Saving settings to "/home/gg-allin/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
  23:35:58.479 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Unable to connect to server. Please check the messages window for more info.
  Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
  Cannot connect to server request channel
  jack server is not running or cannot be started
  JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
  JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock'' Any ideas what i should do?

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 0/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: U192k [UMC202HD 192k], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC282 Analog [ALC282 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: Does `aplay -D hw:0 something.wav` work? Is the first card the device you want to use (see the output of `aplay -l`)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how i can check if ''aplay -D hw:0 something.wav'' work.
tried typing it to terminal and got this [1 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMGXW.png) ''aplay: main:788: audio open error: No such file or directory'' and by typing ''aplay -l'' to terminal i get- [2 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBU2Z.png)
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 0/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC282 Analog [ALC282 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: U192k [UMC202HD 192k], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0